# Найти следующий и предыдущий элемент на странице из группы элементов

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Допустим, у меня есть такая структура  *html*:

```
<div class="block_right">
  <h1>block 1</h1>
  <div class="object_div"> 
    <p>title 3</p>
    <div><a class="play" id="p3">play</a></div> 
  </div>
  <div class="object_div"> 
    <p>title 2</p>
    <div><a class="play" id="p2">play</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="object_div"> 
    <p>title 8</p>
    <div><a class="play" id="p8">play</a></div> 
  </div>
  <div class="object_div"> 
    <p>title 12</p>
    <div><a class="play" id="p12">play</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Мне нужно с помощью *jquery*, имея клик по одной из кнопок *play*, найти следующую и предыдущую кнопку *play*. Также нужно, что бы выбрался следующий элемент именно из данного блока `class="block_right"`, а на страницы может быть еще подобный в точности блок например `class="block_left"` и других объектов, в котором случайным образом могут и совпадать с текущим блоком. Из него выбрать нельзя конечно, только из текущего.

`next()` не подходит, так как, как видите кнопки *play* идут не подряд. Можно конечно найти родительский `div`, который в моем примере имеет `class="object_div"` далее найти его следующего соседа, а далее искать у этого следующего соседа дочерний элемент с классом *play*. Но это решение не удобное, т.к. создает зависимость js от структуры верстки избыточную, а она может меняться.

Я думаю решением может быть, выбрать все элементы с классом *play* дочерние для `block_right` и из них выбрать элемент следующий для текущего. Как это верно сделать?

Comment: Записывай все значения в JS. В лбов случае, скрипт будет от разметки зависеть, т.к. ты функцию с "разметки" запускаешь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достает id у каждого play, можно переписать под себя как нужно

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var i =0;
 var prev = 0;
 var next = 0;
   $(".play").on("click", function(){
var res = $(".block_right").find(".play")
 i = res.index(this);
 if(i > res.length-1)
 {
  i=0;
 }
 prev = i - 1;
 next = i + 1;
 if(next == 5)
 {
  next=0;
 }
 if(prev == -1)
 {
  prev=0
 }     
 console.log("previus: " + res[prev].id)
 console.log("current: " + res[i].id);
 console.log("next: " + res[next].id)
 console.log(i);
 i++;
   });  
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block_right">
  <h1>block 1</h1>
  <div class="object_div"> 
    <p>title 3</p>
    <div><a class="play" id="p3">play</a></div> 
  </div>
  <div class="object_div"> 
    <p>title 2</p>
    <div><a class="play" id="p2">play</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="object_div"> 
    <p>title 8</p>
    <div><a class="play" id="p8">play</a></div> 
  </div>
  <div class="object_div"> 
    <p>title 12</p>
    <div><a class="play" id="p12">play</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Мне нужен клик именно по одному из play. На практике это плейер. И находить следующий id именно относительно того по какому play кликнули. Как я понял, Вы имеете ввиду, что каждый следующий клик по кнопку test имитируют переход к следующему элементу?

Comment: Скорее мне нужно получить не id у play, а получить порядковый номер, который у Вас i именно нажатого элемента. А далее добавив к нему единичку получить порядковый номер следующего элемента или убрав единичку получить порядковый номер текущего элемента. Ну а далее получить из массива сам этот следующий/предыдущий элемент. Видимо это как то перебирая в цикле все элементы с классом play и находя в них текущий по id можно сделать... Хотя возможно есть более простое решение...

Comment: я вас понял сейчас подумаю как сделать

Comment: а если кликают на первый плей кто преведущий?

Comment: Если кликают на первый, то предыдущий не определен. Если на последний, то следующий не определен, переменная пуста. Зацикливать не нужно. Стрелка назад/вперед в этих случаях просто не активна.

Comment: обновил код, проверьте

Comment: Смотрю обновленный код. А где мы тут получаем значение i именно для данного кликнутого элемента?

Comment: Кажется задача решена. Нужно было найти индекс текущего элемента. Через res.index(this)

Comment: я обновил код проверьте

Comment: спасибо, я уже написал, что то вроде того. У Вас есть неточности. i нужно только внутри функии, определять вне не нужно, инкрементировать тоже не нужно. В целом все так.

Comment: какой функции? вроде все так

Answer (score 0):

Нашел такое решение

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".play").on("click", function(){   
            var block_els = $(".block_right").find(".play");

            var index = block_els.index( this );
            var prev_index = index - 1;
            var next_index = index + 1;

            console.log(index, prev_index, next_index);

            if (prev_index == -1) {
                console.log("not prev_element");
                var prev_el = '';
            } else {
                var prev_el = block_els[prev_index];
            }

            if (next_index > block_els.length-1) {
                console.log("not_next_element");
                var next_el = '';
            } else {
                var next_el = block_els[next_index];
            }
            console.log("prev_el", prev_el, "next_el", next_el);
        });
    });
```

выбираем все .play в блоке. Затем находим index в данной коллекции текущего элемента, с помощью index(this), затем выбираем по индексу из коллекции предыдущий и следующий элемент.